# Elementtree duplicates resulting from embedded child nodes

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to extract elements from the UK Parliamentary record system, Hansard. But the xml is not particularly well formatted. For example, it has structures as follows:
housecommons/debates/section/section/data
housecommons/speeches/section/section/data
housecommons/section/section/data

I have code that can get the data as exampled below. However, this results in duplicate values. I think the reason is that my code does not respect the parent child relationships and instead just searches for each 'section' marker following the first marker.

Could someone advise how I can adapt my code to avoid duplicates?

```
doc = ET.parse(xmlFile)
for house in doc.iter('housecommons'):
    #print ('housecommon', house.tag)
    for debates in house.iter('debates'):
        print ('debates')
        #print (title)
        for section in debates.iter('section'):
            #print ("debates section", section.text)
            #title = ("title", section.find('title').text)
            print('debate section')
            for subsection in debates.iter('section'):
                print("debate subsection", subsection.text)
                #title = ("title", subsection.find('title').text)
                #print(title)
```

n.b. this is the type of thing in the raw xml i'm trying to parse. Without posting the full xml the complex structure might not be fully apparent.

```
<housecommons>
<image src="S6CV0001P0I0103"/>
<col>181</col>
<title>House of Commons</title>
<date format="1981-03-17">Tuesday 17 March 1981</date>
<p id="S6CV0001P0-00854"><i>The House met at half-past Two o'clock</i></p>
<debates>
<section>
<title>PRAYERS</title>
<p id="S6CV0001P0-00855">[MR. SPEAKER <i>in the Chair</i>]</p>
<section>
<title>PRIVATE BUSINESS</title>
<section>
<title>CHARTERHOUSE JAPHET BILL</title>
<p id="S6CV0001P0-00856"><i>Bill read the Third time and passed, with amendments.</i></p>
<section>
<title>BARNSLEY BOROUGH COUNCIL BILL</title>
<p id="S6CV0001P0-00857"><i>Further considered; to be read the Third time.</i></p>
</section>
</section>
</section>
</section>
</housecommons>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and make sure that the sample xml is valid?

Answer (score 0):

the `iter(…)` method will iterate recursively over all the XML sub-tree below it (its children, their children, and so on)

I think you may want to use a structure like this

```
for child in parent:
    if child.tag == 'debates':
         # look further
```

The `iter(…)` method is descending more than one level deep in its search for the tag name you provide. This is why duplicates are showing up.